# Can i restrict peers to access certain functionalities in my contract and giving some the access to them?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-development

i want to make a contract with  functionalities and let other peers access that by giving permissions to certain functionalities to some and other ones to some.

Answer (score 5):

modifiers can be interesting in dealing with such things, one simple example :

```
contract testOnlyBy {
    address master1;
    address master2;

    modifier onlyByMaster1 { if (msg.sender != master1) throw; _ }
    modifier onlyByMaster2 { if (msg.sender != master2) throw; _ }
    modifier onlyByMaster1or2 { if (msg.sender != master1 && msg.sender != master2) throw; _ }

    // "0x6eec66e0133feb5e432584515880afad4be047f0"

    function testOnlyBy(address _master2) {
        master1 = msg.sender;
        master2 = _master2;
    }
    function get() external constant returns(address ret1, address ret2) {
        if (msg.sender == master1 || msg.sender == master2){
             return (master1, master2);
        }
    }
    function getonlyByMaster1() onlyByMaster1 external constant returns(address ret1, address ret2) {
        return (master1, master2);
    }
    function getonlyByMaster2() onlyByMaster2 external constant returns(address ret1, address ret2) {
         return (master1, master2);
    }
    function getonlyByMaster1or2() onlyByMaster1or2 external constant returns(address ret1, address ret2) {
         return (master1, master2);           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible to develop a contract that controls access to certain functionality within a contract via user-defined permissions.

A simple example of this is how many contracts restrict access to certain functionality such that only the owner of the contract can use it.  For example:

```
contract Sample {
  address owner;
  string name;

  function Sample() {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  function setName(string n) {
     if(msg.sender == owner) {
        name = n;
     }
  }
}
```

In this case only the owner is allowed to execute `setName(...)`. This example could be extended to allow more permissions that could be checked via the callers address.

Comment: that's cool but if i have n number of peers ,then it will be difficult for me to add their addresses or something else to restrict from certain functionalities.

Comment: That's only an example of one approach.  The point is Solidity is a turing complete language.  So you have the ability to create what you need